# Scrollable backgroundimage of a tablelayout in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayout

I have a tablelayout with 10x10 (columns x rows), I can **drop** objects into those cells.
I want to add an image (as a background) to that tablelayout that can be **scrollable** and covers all the table cells, the user can upload any image size.

drag/drop is working, my probleme is: I can't scroll the tablebackgound image eventho i set `AutoScroll` to true.
any idea how to fix that

Update:
now i can scroll but the image is displayed in wrong way

```
private void addImage()
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\c1\Desktop\img_Clean.png");
            if (tableLayoutDropZone.BackgroundImage != null) tableLayoutDropZone.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
            tableLayoutDropZone.BackgroundImage = img;
            tableLayoutDropZone.AutoScrollPosition = Point.Empty;
            tableLayoutDropZone.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(img.Width, img.Height);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do **three** things:

- Set `yourTLP.AutoScroll = true` and, of course the `BackgroundImageLayout=None`
- Set a suitable `AutoScrollMinSize`; It should have the same size as the image you use as `BackgroundImage`, i.e. when the image changes you need to reset the `AutoScrollMinSize`
- you need to code the `Paint` event to include this line: `e.Graphics.DrawImage(yourTLP.BackgroundImage, yourTLP.AutoScrollPosition);`

[image]

Here is my code to load a new image:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(someimagepath);
if (yourTLP.BackgroundImage != null) yourTLP.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
yourTLP.BackgroundImage = img;
yourTLP.AutoScrollPosition = Point.Empty;
yourTLP.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(img.Width, img.Height);
```

Note that as the TLP **scrolls the controls** it holds are scrolled as well!

If you want them to stay **fixed** you can do this:

- **Remove** all above settings and code
- Create a `Panel` with the very **same** settings and code
- Set the `BackColor` of your `TLP` to `Transparent`
- Nest it in the `Panel`

You may want to turn on `DoubleBuffering` for smoother scrolling..

Comment: Thanks for your response, but when i scroll the image content is messy please take a look [link](http://imgur.com/3vfDDu3)  eventho i overided the OnPaint method as you said

Comment: Hm, not here. Please update th question to  show the full Paint code ! (Btw I see no errors in the image)

Comment: Did you set the correct `AutoScrollMinSize` ? The scrollbars don't look right for the image width?!

Comment: `BackgroundImage` is set to None in the designer , and I set it only in the method above

Comment: No, `BackgroundImageLayout` !!

Comment: Ah sorry, I just set it to none, now the height is correct, but when i scroll the image is messy [link](https://imgur.com/a/T7Sj5)

Comment: Hm it looks right to me. you have scrolled to the right and the pink object is no longer visible..

Comment: yes but the white box and bleu button are not at there

Comment: Um, are they part of the image??? If they are controls in the TLP see the last part on my answer!

Comment: yes they are part of the image, when i set `BackgroundImageLayout` to Stretch it works [see last image](https://imgur.com/a/T7Sj5) but when I set it to `None` the image is messy

Comment: If the AutoScrollMinSize  is set correctly BackgroundImageLayout .Normal and .Stretch will be the same, as the inner display area of the TLP is large enough for the whole image, i.e. (1911x328) pixels. There must be something else in your code that creates the problems. Do add a fresh TLP and test that it will work just fine!